# Find and Replace using RegEx, without user input

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I am trying to find every instance of a pattern in a range of cells and replace those instances with a string literal.

```
Sub poBoxRegEx(myRange As Range)
    Dim myRegEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
    myRegEx.Pattern = "^[p|P][ |\.]*[o|O|0][\.]* ([b|B]ox[ ]*)"
    myRegEx.ignoreCase = True
    myRegEx.Global = True
    myRegEx.MultiLine = True

    myRange.Value = myRegEx.Replace(myRange.Value, "PO Box ")

End Sub
```

Now every other topic and use case I find online here and else where is creating a function accessible via the function bar. I don't need that because I am not creating something that parses the text in column A and outputs the result to column B. No, I just want this find and replace to replace the original text in the original cell.

Comment: Can you provide the context you're originally trying to find?

Comment: I receive data for mailing lists, which is never consistent. One day I may get a data set with 13 columns, another 50 columns. I never know where "PO Box" (or rather a mangled variant of it) is going to appear. I am looking to replace every instance of inconsistent cases, spaces and dot delimited ("P.O.") with a string literal ("PO Box").

Comment: So is your question about your regex or how to do the replacement?

Comment: Your pattern should be `^[pP][ .]*[oO0][.]* ([bB]ox *)` . don't need to give an `|` inside char class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a loop if your range is greater than one cell.

> ```
> Sub poBoxRegEx(myRange As Range)
>     Dim myRegEx As New VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
>     Dim cell As Range
>     myRegEx.Pattern = "^[p|P][ |\.]*[o|O|0][\.]* ([b|B]ox[ ]*)"
>     myRegEx.ignoreCase = True
>     myRegEx.Global = True
>     myRegEx.MultiLine = True
>
>     for each cell in myRange
>         cell.Value = myRegEx.Replace(cell.Value, "PO Box ")
>     next
> End Sub
> ```

Comment: Good job! Hours of searching and tinkering... you nailed it in much less time.